# write cnn structure in simple words

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

how to write following cnn structure in simple words for better understanding
CNN with 11 layers 3×3×32 Convolutional → Dropout → 2×2 MaxPool → 3×3×64 Convolutional
→ Dropout → 2 × 2 MaxPool → Flatten → Dropout → 1 × 1024 Full
connected → Dropout → 1024 × 10 Fully connected → Softmax

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, please clarify.

Comment: i am just asking to define this structure in plain english i am bit confused

Comment: the way you listed seems pretty clear